# Want to check day already exist

Tags: php, mysql

I am having one table which is having 7days mon,tue...sun i am inserting some records to these fields..if i i select/enter monday or any exisiting day in drop down or text field it should say day alredy exist else it should insert...i am using following code getting some problem with this whenever i insert values its saying day exist if i enter other day which is not existing its coming day exist..can anyone check the below code thank in advance

```
$dexist=$_POST['ext'];
$res=mysql_query("select Day from mess where Day='".$dexist."' ");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
    $dy=$row['Day'];
}

if($dy==$dexist)
{
    echo"<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>window.alert('Day exist')</SCRIPT>";
}

else
{
    mysql_query("insert into mess (Date,Day,Breakfast,StartTimeb,EndTimeb,Lunch,StartTimel,EndTimel,Dinner,StartTimed,EndTimed) values('".$date."','".$day."','".$bre."','".$bres."','".$bree."','".$lun."','".$luns."','".$lune."','".$dinn."','".$dins."','".$dine."')");
}

mysql_close($con);
```

Comment: May I post my ext="'; DROP TABLE mess;" to you?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$dexist=$_POST['ext'];
$res=mysql_query("select Day from mess where Day='".$dexist."' ");
$exists = false;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
    $dy=$row['Day'];
    if($dy==$dexist)
    {
        $exists = true;
        break;
    } else {
        mysql_query("insert into mess (Date,Day,Breakfast,StartTimeb,EndTimeb,Lunch,StartTimel,EndTimel,Dinner,StartTimed,EndTimed) values('".$date."','".$day."','".$bre."','".$bres."','".$bree."','".$lun."','".$luns."','".$lune."','".$dinn."','".$dins."','".$dine."')");
        break;
    }
}
if ( $exists ) {
    echo"<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>window.alert('Day exist')</SCRIPT>";
}
mysql_close($con);
```

Have fun..