# please check validation

Tags: php, mysql

i am inserting day value to database,i want validation like if the day already exist it should say day already exist else it should innsert..please can anyone check the following code... thanks in advance

```
$dexist=$_POST['ext'];
$res=mysql_query("select Day from mess where Day='".$dexist."' ");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
    $dy=$row['Day'];
}

if($dy==$dexist)
{
    echo "<script language=\"javascript\">";
    echo "window.alert ('File already exist');";
    echo "//--></script>";

}
else
{
    mysql_query("insert into mess (Date,Day,Breakfast,StartTimeb,EndTimeb,Lunch,StartTimel,EndTimel,Dinner,StartTimed,EndTimed) values('".$date."','".$day."','".$bre."','".$bres."','".$bree."','".$lun."','".$luns."','".$lune."','".$dinn."','".$dins."','".$dine."')");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script screams "SQL INJECTION!" Please pwn my site!

Also: your code is vulnerable to synchronization issues. For example, a file might be created AFTER you ran a select statement, but BEFORE you ran the INSERT statement. This will cause weird failures. That's why you should do the "select and insert" as a single stored proc (read up on atomic operations - more specifically, this is an instance of a "compare and swap").

Comment: sorry this is not file if(file_exists($dy==$dexist)) this should read as if($dy==$dexist)

Comment: Click "edit" under your question to make changes. And it would help if you said what the problem was.

Answer (score 0):

This is a repost of your question.

*searching for the original..*

**found it..**
[Want to check day already exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802738/want-to-check-day-already-exist)

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that in PHP, it's difficult (impossible?) to do safely. Do it in MySQL by adding a unique index on the `Day` column:

```
ALTER TABLE mess ADD UNIQUE (Day);
```

You can then catch failures of that kind by looking for [`ER_DUP_UNIQUE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_dup_unique) from MySQL.

Use PHP's [`mysql_errno`](https://www.php.net/mysql_errno) to check for error 1169 to catch unique constraint failure.

```
$query_result = mysql_query("insert into mess (Date,Day,Breakfast,StartTimeb,EndTimeb,Lunch,StartTimel,EndTimel,Dinner,StartTimed,EndTimed) values('".$date."','".$day."','".$bre."','".$bres."','".$bree."','".$lun."','".$luns."','".$lune."','".$dinn."','".$dins."','".$dine."')");
// 1169 means a unique constraint failure
if (!$query_result && mysql_errno() == 1169) {
  echo "Oh noes, you tried to insert a value twice!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly never, ever pass unchecked POST/GET data into a MySQL query, it's a massive security hole. Use `mysql_real_escape_string` instead:

```
$res=mysql_query("select Day from mess where Day='" . mysql_real_escape_string($dexist) . "' ");
```

And similar for the latter call.

Secondly, it's not clear what you're asking... please **tell us if the code is not working** somewhere, and any errors you're getting. I think you have a problem with this line:

```
if(file_exists($dy==$dexist))
```

That is passing a boolean value (`$dy==$dexist` will evaluate to true or false) into the `file_exists` function. You need to pass the filename in.